# Hi Can someone explain this picture?

Tags: microeconomics, finance

Why is this graph shaped like the letter"L"？
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have three left shoes and three right shoes, you do not get any additional utility by acquiring another left shoe or 100 more left shoes.

Consequently, for a fixed level of one good, the utility does not increase, giving the L-shaped indifference curves where you are indifferent between $(1,1)$ and $(2,1)$ and $(2000,1)$.

(I’m not completely sold on shoes being perfect complements. After all, if you have two left shoes and a right shoe, you could have a spare shoe for when you find a bug in the house, so there might be slightly more utility from having a second left shoe.)

Comment: @AdamBailey A bug in the house

Comment: Instructions clear: my computer has a boot mark on it. The support line told me to reboot it, so now it has two boot marks.

Answer (score 1):

U(X, Y)=min(X, Y) means that your utility is whichever is lower in x and y.

In other words, if you have a tremendous amount of y but very few x, then your utility is decided by x. The reason is that y is useless without x. Extra y will not bring you any extra utilities.

The reason this graph is L shape is that you can only increase your utility by consuming both more good x and good y. If you spend more money and consume more goods y, you are moving up on your indifference curve, but you are still staying at the same indifference curve. Therefore your utility is not going up.

The exact opposite would be the perfect substitute curve, in which consuming any less amount of good X can be perfectly complemented by the extra consumption in Y.

Comment: Thanks so much!!